# jersey unsupported mediatype with @FormDataParam

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, multipartform-data

i'm new with web services. I'm trying to send an InputStream from an android application to a server that use Jersey 2.22 like Rest framework, but i get a 415 Unsupported media type error. This is my client code( I use AsyncHttpClient of Loopj):

```
   client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
   final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
   requestParams.put("file", myInputStream);

   client.post("MyUrl", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                        if(responseBody != null)
                            System.out.println(new String(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                        System.out.println("Failure");
                    }
                });
```

Server side code is:

```
@Path("/schedule")
public class schedule {

@POST
@Secured
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getScenario(@FormDataParam("file")InputStream payload){

    System.out.println("I'm in");
    //Do stuff with payload
 return Response.ok().build();
}
```

But if instead of @FormDataParam i only put

```
public Response getScenario(InputStream payload)
```

I receive my inputStream without any 415 error(naturally in this case the inputStream contains httpBody too).

Searching on the web i have read about dependencies problem, but all seems ok. Here my pom.xml and Resource Configuration:

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("MyPackages", "org.glassfish.jersey.examples.multipart");
rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Pom.xml

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support: -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: I solved a minute later asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved simply changing the @Consumes annotation from @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
to
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

and removing header from client http request